# AC (230V, 50Hz) line detection using H11aa1

Tags: power-supply, power-line-communication

I am new to Power Electronics, I am working on to AC line detection using H11AA1 IC. Schematic is as shown here[image]. 
With the following calculation, I figured out the resistor value R1=8K
 `R1= ( Vs - V_led)/(10mA) which is in my case  R1=( 230 - 1.5)/(10mA) =22.8K`;
So I added R1 20 K/1Watt but I could not achieve the result;
Has anyone work with H11AA1 IC for the similar purpose, Do I need to change R1 value??
[DataSheet of H11AA1 here](https://www.vishay.com/docs/83608/h11aa1.pdf) vishay.com/docs/83608/h11aa1.pdf

Comment: What voltage is Vcc? What do you measure on pin 5 with an oscilloscope? What’s the purpose of C1?

Comment: @winny here VCC is 5V, at pin 5 using voltameter I observed 1.7v., but when I provide AC supply at the input side of H11AA1 it should change, but it not showing any changes.

Comment: You are going to need an oscilloscope to see that waveform. Why is C1 there and what value does it have?

Comment: I added that cap (of 4.7uF) to stabilize the output if any noise occurs. regarding oscilloscope, I don't have one.

Answer (score 2):

I did the same schematic with R1=330K 1/2w. and C1=10uF. The AC current is 0.737 mAAC.(got from amp meter).  So, the power dissipation is 230 x 0.737 = 169.51 mW( approximately). That's ok with R1 1/2w.

If we don't have C1, this will be a zero crossing circuit. If we have C1, the voltage on pin5 is almost 0 when the AC line still alive and = Vcc when the AC line was gone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Would you explain to me the R1 calculation?

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply.  I was decided to try an error for the R1 with 3 values (100K, 220K, and 330K). Just need to minimize the AC current as much as possible that H11AA1 still working as normal. By using the amp meter without calculation.  :-)

Comment: Okay, So you mean for AC circuitry like above one should work for minimal current but within the operating conditions! Thank you

Comment: Definitely.!  It's still in the operating condition.

Answer (score 0):

I think R1 should be at safe value for H11AA.
Normal working input led is: 10mA, AC 220V/50Hz have peak of 220 * 1.5 ~ 330V so R should be
330/0.01 ~ 33K so this should be the safe value for H11AA input leds
and you should not use C1. R8 10K pull up should be enough to provide signal to the controller (5V), in my case is arduino.

Answer (score -1):

Update: OP's original schematic showed a single LED in the opto-coupler. It now shows either a reverse protection diode or LED.

---

You have no reverse polarity protection on the opto-coupler LED. These can usually withstand about 5 - 20 V reverse bias so it was probably destroyed on the first negative half-cycle.

Replace the H11AA1 and add in a reverse protection diode across the LED.

Comment: https://www.vishay.com/docs/83608/h11aa1.pdf

Comment: In the datasheet, it is given as AC or polarity insensitive input, with that assumption  I did not add the diode