# How do I read the state of AC switch, through a microcrontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, wiring, home-automation

I wanted to read the state of an AC switch using a microcontroller.
S1 is an SPST switch and cannot be changed.

[image]

What circuit will be required for doing this?

I'm using this for my home automation project where I should have both manual and wireless control. This will also help me find the state of the load (on/off.)

Comment: Please describe  what you are trying to do. This switch is probably switching something on and off?

Comment: Voltage, current?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have added more details to it, please let me know if anything else is required.

Comment: I'm struggling to see how you can *"have both manual and electronic controll"*.

Comment: @Andyaka I think If the ? block is solved then it should be possible.

Comment: Think again - the load is exclusively controlled via the relay and the relay is under electronic control with no manual bypass feature that I can see.

Comment: @Andyaka you rightly pointed, there was a mistake in framing question. I meant the uC will read the state of manual switch and command relay or the uC will get commands from a wireless module to command the relay.

Comment: @Rohitsam So, it seems to me that you want to see if someone manually turns on thing A and, if so, you want to also turn on thing B but where the MCU detects that A is on in order to decide to turn on B. Is that about it? Does thing A have a line cord? Or is it built into a wall or something hard to get at?

Comment: hey @jonk this is another interesting use case, but I just wanted to use it for controlling the thing A state manually as well as wirelessly  via a mcu.

Comment: @Rohitsam Okay. So it's the same "thing A" being addressed both manually as well as by wifi. You just don't want the MCU/wifi to do something (either turn it on or turn it off) that isn't wanted, whatever that is. Perhaps if the user manually turns the thing on, you don't want the MCU to wifi it on, too, thus perhaps preventing the user from turning it off. Or maybe you want the MCU to override the manual setting. Whatever, you want some kind of way to make a detection. The same question: does "thing A" have a line cord? Or is it buried in a wall?

Comment: a step-down transformer + full-wave rectifier + filter maybe ?

Comment: @MituRaj Or other wise if I also get Neutral to my ?BLOCK then i could use an optoisolater aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site!

If you really don't need to know the state of the physical switch, but instead know if there is current flowing through the switch, you could use a current sensor to measure that. Something like an [Allegro ACS724](https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/sense/current-sensor-ics/zero-to-fifty-amp-integrated-conductor-sensor-ics/acs724).

As you are tying into high voltages, please be smart.

Comment: Current wouldn't flow until uC knowns the state of the switch and turn the relay on.

Comment: @Rohitsam Why does anything need to be at mains voltage then? Why not just hook the switch up to 5V or something instead?

Comment: @Hearth This was considered to simplify the wiring part So that my module would easy fit inside the switchboard without much change existing wiring.

Answer (score 1):

One way It would solve is if I also have Neutral going into my **?Block** then I could use an AC optoisolator to see if the switch is closed or not.
[image]

[image]

Comment: If this is at full mains voltage, that resistor is probably not nearly enough. Honestly, I'd advise against doing anything at mains voltage if you can avoid it, it's dangerous. But if you must, look into a capacitive dropper.

Comment: @Hearth Definitely Dangerous to play with mains, but Optoisolater will never mess up with my uC part and other DC components, but I fell Capacitive dropper might affect uC or other DC components?

Answer (score 0):

That's something you don't generally want to DIY. You are likely to create a hazardous situation. One way to do it relatively safely, assuming you have a way to separately power a microcontroller, is to introduce a solid state relay. Something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FVHWN82).

You'd wire the physical switch to a circuit something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhM3we.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The MCU could monitor that pin as an input to find out the state of the switch. And if it wanted to, it could also dictate the state of that pin with as output. That's just one possibility. Deciding on a topology that satisfies a set of desired outcomes about precedence and what not is what designing something like this is all about, and that's where you come in.

**UDPATE #1**
As per the update to the OP's question, same idea but two separate connections to the microcontroller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frXZXH.png)</sup>

Comment: This is would defenetly work, but in my case it would be difficult to rewire all the switches with the dc part.

Answer (score 0):

Get a 110V (or whatever voltage you're working with) relay and connect the coil from S1 to neutral.  Then connect C to uP ground, and NO to a uP input with a pullup.  When S1 is closed, that input will go low.  (If you want the opposite polarity, use NC instead of NO.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether the switch is in on/off state, you can try recreating the following circuit :-

[image]

[Source](http://www.bytesofgigabytes.com/embedded/sensing-ac-voltage-using-microcontroller/)

The optocoupler mentioned here is PC817. You can also use H11AA1 instead of PC817.

- Whenever AC voltage is present at the input of optocoupler, output of it would be LOW and microcontroller will receive logic 0 as input.
- And when AC voltage is absent at the input of optocoupler, output of it would be HIGH and microcontroller will receive logic 1 as input.

[Here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/409048) the H11AA1 is used.

Comment: Exactly Now I realized I don't require any bridge rectifier also, A capacitor at the output would solve the need.

Comment: @Rohitsam, Just to let you know using PC817 in this circuit will continuously produces a pulse on each AC cycle when switch is in a constant on position. It won't be a constant on signal rather a pulsating one. You should handle this switch input with care in your software or else you will end up with a pulsating relay.

Comment: With AC this schematic will go beyond 6 Volt reverse rating of the LED. You must use a *bipolar* optocoupler or add an extra diode.